# how to set value in datePicker in ionic 2 automation testing appium

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, appium, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I am working on ionic 2, for automation testing i have used appium and webdriver.io , i'm able to set value where  input type is password or email, generally text input type.

```
<input id="i.email" type="email">
```

and setting value using

```
client.setValue('//*[@id="i.email"]', username)
```

but i want to set value into date picker but i'm unable to do so.. my code is as below..

```
 <ion-datetime id="d.fromDt" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY"
 [(ngModel)]="fromDate" doneText="ok" cancelText="clear"
 displayFormat="DD - MM - YYYY"> </ion-datetime>
```

and i have tried setting value using

```
-- client.setValue('//*[@id="d.fromDt"]', 'May 22 2018')

-- client.element('//*[@id="d.fromDt"]').setValue('May 22 2018')
```

but nothing is working. also getting response from appium **invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it**. can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Could you solve this?